# segmentation fault deleting nodes

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when I compile this code, I believe it is being caused by this block right here.

```
EmployPtr iter;    
//Deletes nodes outside of range.
while(netSalary(iter)<45000 || netSalary(iter)>60000)
{
    EmployPtr nodeToDelete = iter;
    iter = iter->link;
    delete nodeToDelete;
}
```

I find pointers to be very confusing and there is a pointer that is not pointing to a valid object in memory but I'm not sure how to interpret it. I understand that I need to reassign the "next" (or 'link' how I have it named in my code) pointer of the object before the one being deleted, to the next pointer, after the object being deleted. I tried to do that with code but I'm still getting the seg fault. Can anyone explain to me what is going on and help me understand how to fix this?

```
        EmployPtr nodeToDelete = iter->link;
        iter->link = nodeToDelete->link;
        delete nodeToDelete;
```

[Included the rest of the code in-case it needs to be referenced.]

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Employee
{
    string firstN;
    string lastN;
    float salary;
    float bonus;
    float deduction;

    Employee *link;
};

typedef Employee* EmployPtr;
void insertAtHead( EmployPtr&, string, string, float, float,float );
void insert( EmployPtr&, string, string, float, float,float );
float netSalary( EmployPtr& );

int main()
{
    //Open file
    fstream in( "payroll.txt", ios::in );

    //Read lines
    string first, last;
    float salary, bonus, deduction;
    EmployPtr head = new Employee;

    //Inserts all the data into a new node in the linked list, creating a new node each time the loop executes.
    while( in >> first >> last >> salary >> bonus >> deduction)
        insert (head, first, last, salary, bonus, deduction);

    //Close file
    in.close();

    cout << "\t\t\t\t-Salary in the range of ($45,000 - $60,000)-\n" << "Printed in format: First Name, Last Name, Salary, Bonus, Deduction, Net Salary.\n\n";

    //Deletes all nodes in the list that are not between 45,000 and 65,000. It then prints the newly modified list.
    EmployPtr iter;
    for(iter = head; iter!= NULL; iter = iter->link)
    {
        //Deletes nodes outside of range.
        while(netSalary(iter)<45000 || netSalary(iter)>60000)
        {
            EmployPtr nodeToDelete = iter;
            iter = iter->link;
            delete nodeToDelete;
        }

        //Prints list.
        cout << iter->firstN << ", " << iter->lastN << ", " << iter->salary << ", " << iter->bonus << ", " << iter->deduction << ", " << netSalary(iter) <<endl;
    }
        return 0;
}

void insertAtHead(EmployPtr& head, string firstValue, string lastValue,
            float salaryValue, float bonusValue,float deductionValue)
{
    //method definition
}

void insert(EmployPtr& afterNode, string firstValue, string lastValue,
        float salaryValue, float bonusValue,float deductionValue)
{
    //method definition
}

float netSalary(EmployPtr& node)
{
   //method definition
}
```

[Updated Code]

```
    //Deletes nodes outside of range.
    while((netSalary(head)<45000 || netSalary(head)>60000) && head!=NULL)
    {
        EmployPtr nodeToDelete = head;
        head = head->link;
        delete nodeToDelete;
        nodeToDelete->link = head;
    }

        //Prints List
    EmployPtr iter;
    for(iter = head; iter!= NULL; iter = iter->link)
    {
        cout << iter->firstN << ", " << iter->lastN << ", " << iter->salary << ", " << iter->bonus << ", " << iter->deduction << ", " << netSalary(iter) <<endl;
    }
```

Comment: if you find pointers confusing, then 1. switch to a managed language, 2. or at least use `std::list`.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option for me, and I have guidelines that state that I have to implement my own list so that is also not an option.

Comment: Getting a segmentation fault while compiling? Really ?? Do compiler really give segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

In your while cycle the iter can point to end of the list then in netSalary(iter) you passed null pointer (if I assume that your list is end by null pointer). Is your function ok with that? Or you just have something like return iter->salary;

EDIT:
It is just a guess since you didn't provide the implementation of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens when the last element of the list has a net salary below 45000 or above 60000.  The 'link' pointer of the last element will (presumably) be NULL, but your inner loop does not check for that, so after deleting that element, it will pass a NULL pointer to the netSalary function.

You must jump all the way out of the *outer* loop when you reach the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I see two similar problems.

One is that you have iter = iter->link twice.  Once is in the for loop, and once is in the while loop.  You probably only need one controlling loop here.

The other is that the while() loop never checks if iter is null.

So imagine the following data set: 15000, 16000

The for loop points at the 15000 node.  Now it hits the while loop.  Since 15000 is out of range, it does iter = iter->link and iter now points at the 16000 node.  Then it deletes the 15000 node.  The while loop runs again and sees that 16000 is out of range.  It does iter = iter->link and now iter points at null.  It deletes the 16000 node.  The while loop runs again, but now you pass it null!

I would change this to use either a while loop or a for loop, and have only one place that checks for null and moves on to the next node.

Comment: I wasnt sure how to add code into the comments so i added it as an edit to yours. What you are saying makes sense so I tried to fix it based off if that. I fixed the dangling pointer and moved the for loop down so I could use it to print the list but now all i'm getting is the same node printed over and over again..

Comment: Ok I guess my revisions didn't show up so I added them back to the main question.

Comment: No crash!  That's an improvement!  I'm not sure why it is printing the same node over and over again.  The print loop looks right.  I do see a problem with the while loop.  Think about what happens if the first node is 50000, but the second one is 15000.  At this point, you should probably be using a debugger.  It will give you great insight as to what is happening.  If you don't know how to use one, lots of printf or cout lines will help you to inspect what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you fix it or not, but I saw that when you destroy a node you don't remove the previous link to the deleted item. I've tried something, hope it help

```
EmployPtr iter = head;
EmployPtr prevIt = NULL; // pointer to previous node
while( iter )
{
    if(netSalary(head)<45000 || netSalary(head)>60000)
    {
        EmployPtr nodeToDelete = iter;
        iter = iter->link;
        delete nodeToDelete;

        if( prevIt )
            prevIt->link = iter;
        else
            head = iter; // this happens when the head needs to be deleted, so head must point to nex
    }
    else
    {
        prevIt = iter;
        iter = iter->link;
    }
}
```